# Change UIAlertController separator line color

Tags: swift, xcode, uialertcontroller

I can not really find any info on how to change `UIAlertController` separator linecolor as you can barely even see it with blue background color. (changing bg color is not an option)
I would appreciate any info on how to do that, thanks
[image]

Comment: Use your own `UIView` object for further customization.

Comment: how would I do that?